# How to draw a box within an HTML element?

Tags: html, css

I have a Web app that is producing HTML roughly like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <span>Header</span>
    <div id="element">
        <img src="something"/>
    </div>
    <span>Version 1.0</span>
</div>
```

looking roughly like this:

[image: First example]

Server-side processing gives me coordinates *within* the image that I'd like to highlight (say, by drawing a red box on top of the image). What I'm hoping to do is something like:

```
<div id="container">
    <span>Header</span>
    <div id="element">
        <img src="something"/>
        <div id="highlight" style="width:30px;height:10px;top:10px;left:10px"/>
    </div>
    <span>Version 1.0</span>
</div>
```

(where the coordinates are generated in the HTML source by the server) looking roughly like this:

[image: Second example]

with:

```
#highlight: {
   position: absolute;
   border: 2px solid red;
}
#element: {
   position: relative;
}
```

But instead I'm getting:

[image: Third example]

where the last span is inside the element that was just closed. What am I missing?

**Update**

I edited the question to get rid of a typo, but left in the error that was actually causing the problem.

Comment: You're missing a closing " in 
        <div id="highlight" style="width:30px;height:10px;top:10px;left:10px/> and you shouldn't be closing it in with a /> in the first place :)

Comment: Sigh. That was a typo in transcribing the HTML. Could you take back the -1, please?

Comment: I didn't downvote. Anyway, have you tried a simple float on the span element?

Comment: Closing the div with an explicit end tag did it. I hadn't realized that you can't do that. That makes me wonder if I should use something besides a div for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of errors!

### Error 1:

```
<div id="highlight" style="width:30px;height:10px;top:10px;left:10px!!!!!/>
```

Missing end quote:

```
<div id="highlight" style="width:30px;height:10px;top:10px;left:10px"/>
```

### Error 2:

A div cannot close itself:

```
<div id="container">
    <span>Header</span>
    <div id="element">
        <img src="something"/>
        <div id="highlight" style="width:30px;height:10px;top:10px;left:10px"!!!!/>
    </div>
    <span>Version 1.0</span>
</div>
```

Fixed:

```
<div id="container">
    <span>Header</span>
    <div id="element">
        <img src="something"/>
        <div id="highlight" style="width:30px;height:10px;top:10px;left:10px"></div>
    </div>
    <span>Version 1.0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Error 1 was just a typo, but error 2 was the problem. Thanks!